# How do I remove the updatetoolnotifier from launchctl?

Tags: launchd

Over a year ago I was working with the Glassfish app server. It apparently installed an "update notifier" that occasionally checks for updates and presents a dialog like this:

[image: app update image]

Since I'm no longer using this server (go Tomcat!) I'd like to stop getting these update messages. Through some `ps -f` spelunking I see that it's running

```
/Users/myusername/Library/Application Support/updatetool/notifier
```

and that the parent pid launching it is `launchctl`. I'm aware that I can just blow away the $HOME/glassfish dir, or perhaps the `updatetool` dir, but that would leave behind whatever bits are telling `launchctl` to run its occasional updates. I'd prefer a clean removal.

I see that it's running with the following:

```
$ launchctl list | grep -i update
494 -   [0x0-0x3c03c].net.java.updatecenter.updatetoolnotifier
```

In the past I've tried removing the entry via

```
launchctl remove [0x0-0x3c03c].net.java.updatecenter.updatetoolnotifier
```

But that seems to have no effect; it always comes back. How can I remove Glassfish cleanly, and prevent it from trying to update itself after removal?

Comment: By "it always comes back" do you mean that the launchd job is deleted and then reappears?

Comment: @eyemth- yes. I delete it, it appears gone, and then a week later it's back.